# move function body, avoiding full cloning

Tags: c++, optimization, llvm, cloning

This is a follow up question from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5369790/170521).

I am using `llvm::CloneFunctionInto` defined in `llvm/Transforms/Utils/Cloning.h` in order to create a new function after code generation with the right signature inferred from the type of the return values. This works nicely but it is slow

I am trying to optimize this a little bit by some way to move or transfer the function body from the old function to the new one, is there a utility for that?

I am trying to hack a way to do the transfer by looking at the [code in CloneFunctionInto](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/CloneFunction_8cpp_source.html), but wanted to see if an existing function exists

Answer (score 5):

Shamelessly stolen from the [Arg Promotion pass](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ArgumentPromotion_8cpp_source.html) (search for splice):

```
// Since we have now created the new function, splice the body of the old
// function right into the new function, leaving the old rotting hulk of the
// function empty.
NF->getBasicBlockList().splice(NF->begin(), F->getBasicBlockList());
```

Where `NF` is the new function you're cloning into and `F` is the old function that you have just cloned.

Comment: This doesn't cover arguments. We need part of the remaining code in that pass.